# Getting CWNetwork data rates

Tags: objective-c, macos, networking, corewlan

I'm trying to get the data rates (in Mbps) for a CWNetwork object using CoreWLAN but I'm not able to figure out how to do this.

I've searched through all the API documentation and even the private methods for the CWNetwork and CWChannel objects.

What's the correct way of getting this information?

Answer (score 0):

class `CWInterface` has `transmitRate` property. This property returns the current transmit rate (Mbps) for the interface.

```
CWInterface *wifiInterface = [CWInterface interface];
NSLog("Transmit Rate - %.f Mbps", wifiInterface.transmitRate);
```

Output - 145 Mbps